# Entailment and resolution proof

Tags: logic

If $\sum$ entails $\alpha$, where $\sum$ is a set of well formed formulas ie $\{a \implies b, b \implies c \}$ then does $\sum \vdash_{\text{Res}} \alpha$?

Comment: Not clear... Do you mean: if $\Sigma$ entails $\alpha$, then we can prove by *resolution* that $\Sigma \vdash \alpha$ ?

Comment: If so, YES: [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) "when coupled with a complete search algorithm, yields a sound and complete algorithm for deciding the satisfiability of a propositional formula, and, by extension, the validity of a sentence under a set of axioms."